# Creating large amount of mailboxes on Exchange 2003

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, exchange-server

I've got around 750+ users that I'm going to create mailboxes for. Should I sleep for a bit between creates to not overload the exchange server or does it not matter? I've read that the actual mailbox is not created until the user accesses it or they get mail. I'm using CDOEXM and DirectoryServices in .NET 2.0.

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports CDOEXM

...
...

Dim mbx As IMailboxStore = user.NativeObject
mbx.CreateMailbox(store)
user.CommitChanges()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just go for it.  I wouldn't expect only 750 to cause any sort of operational problem on anything resembling a modern server.

Answer (score 0):

Exchage defers most of the work until the user logs in for the first time, so creating the mailboxes shouldn't be much work.